# Batch finding and operation Display partially duplicate files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a question. Is it possibile in batch language to search and display files which first five letter in filename are the same.. This folder contains thousands of files. For example

```
22222rewrs344234w.mp3

22222asdqweavasd.mp3

234seqwe.mp3

32434.mp3

qwedasdasdasd.mp3

qwedasasdasd.mp3

11122asdas.mp3

11122asdasd.mp3

...

...

...
```

I need to display in cmd only names of files

```
22222rewrs344234w.mp3

22222asdqweavasd.mp3

11122asdas.mp3

11122asdasd.mp3

qwedasdasdasd.mp3

qwedasasdasd.mp3
```

Because the first five letter are the same.If the folder does not contain a 5 character duplicates it prints a message folder 
Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: would you consider another option to do that? like python for example?

Comment: I know it's possible in python and probably I advised me to deal with this , but i need to know is it possible in batch language in windows without 
external compiler

Comment: What _Message folder_? Just read, what you wrote in your question? Do you know what punctuation marks are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Group files with same 5 chars prefix in name
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "file=%%a"
   for /F %%f in ("!file:~0,5!") do set "group[%%f]=!group[%%f]! %%a"
)

rem Show groups that have more than one name
for /F "tokens=2*" %%a in ('set group[') do (
   if "%%b" neq "" echo Same prefix: %%a %%b
)
```

Comment: I agree, your solution is much better. I wasn't aware of those dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for help! You are awesome!:)